# Iterating through a dataframe with info from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a question that I think is more about logic than about coding. My goal is to calculate how many Kilometers a truck is loaded and charging.

I have two Dataframes

Lets call the first one trips:

```
Date         Licence   City             State    KM
01/05/2019   AAA-1111  Sao Paulo        SP       10
02/05/2019   AAA-1111  Santos           SP       10
03/05/2019   AAA-1111  Rio de Janeiro   RJ       20
04/05/2019   AAA-1111  Sao Paulo        SP       15
01/05/2019   AAA-2222  Curitiba         PR       20
02/05/2019   AAA-2222  Sao Paulo        SP       25
```

Lets call the second one invoice

```
Code Date       License  Origin    State Destiny        UF   Value
A1   01/05/2019 AAA-1111 Sao Paulo SP    Rio de Janeiro RJ   10.000,00
A2   01/05/2019 AAA-2222 Curitiba  PR    Sao Paulo      SP  15.000,00
```

What I need to get is:

```
Date         Licence   City             State        KM  Code
01/05/2019   AAA-1111  Sao Paulo        SP       10  A1
02/05/2019   AAA-1111  Santos           SP       10  A1
03/05/2019   AAA-1111  Rio de Janeiro   RJ       20  A1
04/05/2019   AAA-1111  Sao Paulo        SP       15  Nan
01/05/2019   AAA-2222  Curitiba         PR       20  A2
02/05/2019   AAA-2222  Sao Paulo        SP       25  A2
```

As I said, is more a question of logic. The truck got its cargo in the initial point that is São Paulo. How can I iterate through the rows knowing that it passed through Santos loaded and then went to Rio de Janeiro if I don´t have the date when the cargo was delivered?

tks

Answer (score 0):

Assume the rows in the first dataframe(df1) are sorted, here is what I would do:

**Note:** below I am using `df1` for trips and `df2` for invoice

1. Left join with the df1 (left) and df2 (right) using as much information that is valid for matching two dataframes, so that we can find rows in df1 which are **Origin** of the trips. In my test, I am using the fields: *['Date', 'License', 'City', 'State']*, save the result in a new dataframe `df3`

   ```
   df3 = df1.merge(df2[df2.columns[:6]].rename(columns={'Origin':'City'})
           , on = ['Date', 'License', 'City', 'State']
           , how = 'left'
   )
   ```

   [image]
2. fill the NULL values in df3.Desitiny with `ffill()`

   ```
   df3['Destiny'] = df3.Destiny.ffill()
   ```
3. setup the group label by the following flag:

   ```
   g = (~df3.Code.isnull() | (df3.shift().City == df3.Destiny)).cumsum()
   ```

   [image]

   **Note:** I added df3['g'] in the above picture for reference
4. update df3.Code using ffill() based on the above group labels.

   ```
   df3['Code'] = df3.groupby(g).Code.ffill()
   ```